# Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'C:\Config.Msi' Expo eas build

Tags: windows, react-native, expo

I’ve been trying to do an EAS build but I keep getting this error

I have tried clearing my cache, uninstalling node and reinstalling it. Creating a new app entirely and moving the source code and dependencies over. installing Expo 45. downgraded to expo 44.

EAS diagnostics

```
  EAS CLI 0.52.0 environment info:
    System:
      OS: Windows 10 10.0.19043
    Binaries:
      Node: 16.15.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
      Yarn: 1.22.4 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn.CMD
      npm: 8.10.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
    Utilities:
      Git: 2.33.0.
    npmPackages:
      expo: ^44.0.0 => 44.0.6
      expo-updates: ~0.11.7 => 0.11.7
      react: 17.0.1 => 17.0.1
      react-dom: 17.0.1 => 17.0.1
      react-native: 0.64.3 => 0.64.3
      react-native-web: 0.17.1 => 0.17.1
    Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'C:\Config.Msi'
    Code: EPERM
```

Eas version
eas-cli/0.52.0 win32-x64 node-v16.15.0

Thank you in advance for your help!